# Google web-fonts huge during pre-load

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm halfway through designing and developing **this:** http://bit.ly/18bQOKS WordPress website for a client.

I'm using REMs for the first time (using this method: http://gregrickaby.com/using-the-golden-ratio-and-rems) to handle font size and line height.

Whilst the page loads, all of the fonts appear much larger for a few seconds in Chrome. Could I prevent this issue by using the bullet proof @font-face method?

Thanks!

S

Comment: How are you loading the font?

Comment: I'm using the non js method with an @import via my stylesheet. The Chrome bug has been registered here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319623

Comment: Also here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=320754. For some weird reason, switching to JS font loader this morning seemed to fix it for me. Could be a fluke.

Comment: It's driving me potty! I'll try the JS loader :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding the * selector solved the problem.

```
html{font-size:62.5%}
*{font-size:16px;font-size:1.6rem;line-height:1.75}
body{color:#444}
```

You can read more on the * selector here: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw